# Where is a definitive guide for rewriting my test classes in the face of setMethods() deprecation?

Tags: phpunit

`MockBuilder::setMethods()` method got deprecated in 8.3, but examples in the documentation still use it, and I can't find a definitive migration guide anywhere. Does one exist?

Out of respect for your time potentially spent writing an answer: answers boiling down to "just keep using `setMethods()`, it still works" will not be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setMethods()` has been deprecated as of this [PR](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3687)

At this moment of the time documentation are outdated but I guess they will be fixed in no time. To answer your question about `setMethods` it has been replaced with two new functions

- onlyMethods

```
 /**
 * Specifies the subset of methods to mock, requiring each to exist in the class
 *
 * @param string[] $methods
 *
 * @throws RuntimeException
 */
 public function onlyMethods(array $methods): self
 {...}
```

- addMethods

```
/**
* Specifies methods that don't exist in the class which you want to mock
*
* @param string[] $methods
*
* @throws RuntimeException
*/
public function addMethods(array $methods): self
{...}
```

**Example**

Old Code might have looked like this

```
$merchant = $this->getMockBuilder('\Fake\FakeMerchant')
    ->setMethods(['getLegalEntity'])
    ->getMock();
```

which should be now like this

```
$merchant = $this->getMockBuilder('\Fake\FakeMerchant')
    ->addMethods(['getLegalEntity'])
    ->getMock();
```

**Extra Information**

I didn't find the definitive migration guide but since I recently 
had to migrate from old `phpunit 4.x` to new `phpunit 8.4` here are the tips that you can follow.

- `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` has been replaced with `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`
- `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject` has been replaced with `PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject`
- `->getMock` has been removed. So the alternative is either `->createMock()`, `createPartialMock` or `->getMockBuilder()->getMock()`
- Functions like `setUp` `setUpBeforeClass`, `tearDown`, etc now need to define `::void` return type
- `mockObject->setMethods` is deprecated and should be replaced with `onlyMethod` for method that already exists and `addMethods` for methods that does exists on the class
- `@expectedException` from docblock is deprecated and `$this->setExpectedException` has been removed